# Skype integration with Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, skype

We are developing iOS app in Xamarin and we have one requirement to integrate O365 Skype integration. I can see there is SDK available for iOS native but couldn't find anything for Xamarin.iOS. Anyone please help me out.

Comment: Well, the idea behind a shared codebase, which xamarin provides, is that it will run on multiple platforms. So the library/SDK you found, will most likely run on Xamarin.Android aswell as Xamarin.iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you look for is called a iOS library binding.

If someone already created it and made open-source you can look for it. If not - it is necessary to you to do a binding.

Please see reference https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/ about ios libraries bindings.